# Devise Invitable getting wrong params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise-invitable

What I'm getting after sending invite to the user:
/users/invitation/accept.37?`invitation=_token=`3DpoDuVJ5EJcqmHAmbCJTz

What It should be:
/users/invitation/accept.37?`invitation_token=`3DpoDuVJ5EJcqmHAmbCJTz

I tried to see if the problem was from routes, or maybe from the url but the url is being mounted this way:

```
<%= accept_invitation_url(@resource, invitation_token: @token) %>
```

Comment: Having a `.` in your unique identifier is quite problematic since Rails uses it when specifying the format - unless you specify your own regex in the route definition you'll get "Unknown Format 37". Any good reason why your routes are so strange? https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments

Comment: accept_user_invitation GET    /users/invitation/accept(.:format)         users/invitations#edit
  
this is the route made by devise in routes.rb: devise_for :users, controllers: { invitations: "users/invitations" }

Comment: Did you try just using `accept_invitation_url(invitation_token: @token)`? The route doesn't actually have a placeholder for an ID - that's passed through the token.